# How to change IP address of wifi interface using python in linux?

Tags: python, wifi

I want to change ip address of the wifi interface using python. How can I do it? You don't have to tell me the code. Just point me out. I'll hunt down. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean change the LOCAL IP address, or to flush to worldwide one, and get a new one from you ISP?

Comment: You can use subprocess, and call iwconfig http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: there is `nmcli` (command-line interface for NetworkManager). For older version there is [cnetworkmanager that is implemented in Python and uses D-Bus to talk to NetworkManeger](http://vidner.net/martin/software/cnetworkmanager/)).

Comment: @InbarRose Actualy what I want is to change my wifi card IP address so I can broadcast using it at initial IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to execute [ifconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) from python and pass it the interface options like the `ip` and `broadcast` addresses and so on, for example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ifconfig", "eth0", "192.168.1.5", "netmask", "255.255.255.0", "broadcast", "192.168.2.255"])
```

Edit:
There's also a python package that parses config files, you could use that to set the interface options, check this question
[Is there any python package that could configure IP address of network interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865920/is-there-any-python-package-that-could-configure-ip-address-of-network-interface)